# Diferença na utilização Indice Unique e Unique Constraint no Sql Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, restrição-único

Gostaria de saber qual o comportamento/diferenças entre um **Indice Unique** e **Unique Constraints** para o **Sql Server** ?

Muitos devem pensar que isso não faz diferença no banco de dados, mas faz!
E não só para o DBA/Administrador, mas para os desenvolvedores também pois pode influenciar como um código é escrito.

---

Como referencia do que pode ser tão diferente e que estou interessado em saber segue abaixo um exemplo de como é em um banco **Informix** , mas no SQL Server como funciona?

> ## Indice UNIQUE
>
> - Pode ser criado/apagado ONLINE, com usuários utilizando a tabela
>     Isso pode pesar muito na manutenção de sistemas 24x7.  * A validação
>     da unicidade é feita linha a linha.     Um exemplo simples, seria como
>     executar um `UPDATE tp01 SET cod = cod + 1;` em uma tabela que o campo
>     *cod* é sequencial e com indice unico, este update daria erro na 1a linha pois já duplicaria   * Como todos os demais bancos de dados, não
>     pode ser utilizado como referencia de Foreign keys...
>
> ## Unique Constraint
>
> *(ou mesmo primary key constraint)*
>
> - Não pode ser apagado/criado com usuários acessando a tabela, mesmo
>     que apenas leitura.     Em outras palavras é preciso acesso exclusivo
>     na tabela para realizar uma manutenção.    Isso é péssimo em sistemas
>     24x7.    * A validação é feita no final do bloco do *statement*     No
>     caso do `UPDATE tp01 SET cod = cod + 1;` , funcionaria sem problemas
>     pois ele irá validar a unicidade só quando finalizar a atualização de
>     todas as linhas envolvidas.  * É possivel adiar a validação da
>     constraint apenas no final da transação.      Isto é, no momento do
>     `commit`. Isso é possível quando for utilizado o comando `set
>     constraints [all|<constraint>] deffered;` antes das atualizações.
>     Assim no exemplo do update acima, ele só vai validar a unicidade
>     quando o *commit* for enviado para o banco.     *Obs.: Este recurso
>     vale para todos os tipos de constraints (PK, FK, UK)*

Fonte: [Diferença na utilização Indice Unique e Unique Constraint no Informix?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/diferenca-na-utilizacao-indice-unique-e-unique-constraint-no-informix)

Lembrando, a descrição acima é como o IBM Informix trabalha. Gostaria de saber como é nos outros bancos e entender quais as limitações ou recursos adicionais que podemos prover para os desenvolvedores.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Em termos de performance e assertividade os dois são praticamente equivalentes:

> A unique index guarantees that the index key contains no duplicate values and therefore every row in the table is in some way unique. **There are no significant differences between creating a UNIQUE constraint and creating a unique index that is independent of a constraint. Data validation occurs in the same manner, and the query optimizer does not differentiate between a unique index created by a constraint or manually created.** However, creating a UNIQUE constraint on the column makes the objective of the index clear.

[(Fonte)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms187019.aspx)

Além da própria ressalva, o restante da documentação do MSDN pouco tenta diferenciar as duas maneiras.

---

Apesar da semelhança ressaltada pela documentação no MSDN, [um dos nossos sites *irmãos* possui uma resposta que demonstra algumas pequenas diferenças](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/55139):

- Violação de uma *unique constraint* retorna um erro 2627, enquanto de uma *unique index* retorna 2601.
- Uma *unique constraint* não pode ser desabilitada, enquanto com uma *unique index* é possível.
- *unique constraints* suportam `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` e `FILLFACTOR` (pode ser dependente da versão do SQL).
- *unique constraint* não podem ser filtrados (?)

Comment: Talles, obrigado pela resposta, mas não vou assinalar ela ainda porque não foi esclarecida uma das minhas duvidas principais, o que esta diferença pode mudar para o desenvolvedor, no seu controle de código/transacional , ou não muda nada?  Obrigado mesmo assim, assinalei sua resposta como util.

Answer (score 1):

A unique key garante a unicidade de informações na sua tabela, a primary key também porém esta última pode ser utilizada para relacionamentos de foreign key com outras tabelas.

Geralmente chaves únicas também pode ter registros nulos, por isso não podem ser chave primária. Deve-se ficar atento a isso.