# Diferença na utilização Indice Unique e Unique Constraint no Informix?

Tags: sql, restrição-único, informix

Gostaria de saber qual o comportamento/diferenças entre um **Indice Unique** e **Unique Constraints** para o **Informix** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Muitos devem pensar que isso não faz diferença no banco de dados, mas faz!
E não só para o DBA/Administrador, mas para os desenvolvedores também pois pode influenciar como um código é escrito.

Trabalho muito com **IBM Informix** e nele sei que existe as diferenças abaixo.

## Indice UNIQUE

- Pode ser criado/apagado ONLINE, com usuários utilizando a tabela
  Isso pode pesar muito na manutenção de sistemas 24x7.
- A validação da unicidade é feita linha a linha.
  Um exemplo simples, seria como executar um `UPDATE tp01 SET cod = cod + 1;` em uma tabela que o campo *cod* é sequencial e com indice unico, este update daria erro na 1a linha pois já duplicaria
- Como todos os demais bancos de dados, não pode ser utilizado como referencia de Foreign keys...

## Unique Constraint

*(ou mesmo primary key constraint)*

- Não pode ser apagado/criado com usuários acessando a tabela, mesmo que apenas leitura.
  Em outras palavras é preciso acesso exclusivo na tabela para realizar uma manutenção. 
  Isso é péssimo em sistemas 24x7.
- A validação é feita no final do bloco do *statement*
  No caso do `UPDATE tp01 SET cod = cod + 1;` , funcionaria sem problemas pois ele irá validar a unicidade só quando finalizar a atualização de todas as linhas envolvidas.
- É possivel adiar a validação da constraint apenas no final da transação.
  Isto é, no momento do `commit`. Isso é possível quando for utilizado o comando `set constraints [all|<constraint>] deffered;` antes das atualizações.
  Assim no exemplo do update acima, ele só vai validar a unicidade quando o *commit* for enviado para o banco.
  *Obs.: Este recurso vale para todos os tipos de constraints (PK, FK, UK)*